# Using a ProjectionExpression with reserved words with Boto3 in DynamoDB

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm selecting data from my DynamoDB database using boto3

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table(table_name)
response = table.scan(ProjectionExpression='Id,Name')['Items']
```

Works fine. Now I also want to retrieve an attribute that is (unfortunately) named with a reserved word - let's say `CONNECTION`.

```
response = table.scan(ProjectionExpression='Id,Name,Connection')['Items']
```

I get an error like

> An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Scan
>   operation: Invalid ProjectionExpression: Attribute name is a reserved
>   keyword; reserved keyword: Connection

I know there's an aliasing technique if using filters or queries, but does this exist for simple projections from boto3?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Turns out that this is easily solved the same as when calling the DynamoDB API directly.

We should use an alias for any reserved word, and then provide a mapping from the alias back to the 'true' name with the [ExpressionAttributeName](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.html) parameter/property.

```
response = table.scan(ProjectionExpression = 'Id, Name, #c',
                      ExpressionAttributeNames = {'#c': 'Connection'})['Items']
```

Comment: For Java : .withProjectionExpression("Id,Name,#c").withNameMap(new HashMap<String, String>() {{put("#c", "Connection");}})