# dynamodb.getItem returns {} when searching for a record that ends with ID

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I've hit a weird problem where `dynamodb.getItem` returns {} when I specify a parameter that ends with ID:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({ region: "ap-southeast-2" });
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: '2012-08-10' });

const tableName = "ReportingDB"
async function logReports() {
    try {
        var params = {
            Key: {
                "Category": { "S": "Certification" },
                "Report": { "S": "By EmployeeID" }
            },
            TableName: tableName
        };
        var result = await dynamodb.getItem(params).promise()
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
   } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
}
```

When I change the value "By EmployeeID" to "By Employee Number" it then works, why?

```
async function logReports() {
    try {
        var params = {
            Key: {
                "Category": { "S": "Certification" },
                "Report": { "S": "By Employee Number" }
            },
            TableName: tableName
        };
        var result = await dynamodb.getItem(params).promise()
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
   } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
}
```

To reproduce, create a DynamoDB table with two columns Category and Report, then add an item with "Certification" and "By EmployeeID/Number" values respectively.

The error handling in DynamoDB is pretty good, typically it will fail with an error message such as Reserved keyword (eg [Using a ProjectionExpression with reserved words with Boto3 in DynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52994822/495455)) however with "By EmployeeID" it doesn't produce any error, it just doesn't return anything. Could it be a bug or something I don't know about? I couldn't find it documented.

PS I've inserted the values in the dynamo db using the web console.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation for GetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html) explains that:

> If there is no matching item, GetItem does not return any data and there will be no Item element in the response.

In other words, if there is no item matching the given key, you'll get an empty result - not an error message. I suspect that this is exactly what is happening in your case.

I don't know why it didn't find an item with "By EmployeeID". I don't think it's a bug involving the letters "ID" :-) I suspect that you simply have a bug in the code which inserted this item, perhaps mis-spelling the word "By EmployeeID". Please look again at the code which inserts this item, or use the AWS DynamoDB UI (or do a `Scan` request) to inspect the contents of your table manually to see what it actually contains.

Comment: That's a good idea about doing the scan and copy pasting that value, even though I triple checked. And that's something I didn't explain that I inserted the values using the web console