# dynamodb getting issue on getting attributes

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I want to get specific attributes(columns) in my dynamo query and getting error .

```
    table = get_dynamodb_table()
    response = table.query(
        AttributesToGet=["USER_ID","NODE_TYPE"],
        IndexName='GSI3',
        KeyConditionExpression="GSI3_ACCOUNT_PK = 2 AND GSI3_UPDATED_ON BETWEEN 1231231 AND123")
```

but when I am trying to run this I am getting this error

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Can not use both expression and non-expression parameters in the same request: Non-expression parameters: {AttributesToGet} Expression parameters: {KeyConditionExpression}
```

Comment: Probably because you have some strange quotations marks `""`?

Comment: @Marcin  sorry that mistake on copying on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ProjectionExpression` instead. As the docs at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LegacyConditionalParameters.AttributesToGet.html explain, `AttributesToGet` is an older style and doesn’t work in combo with newer expression features. That’s what the error means.

Comment: so here I have to pass comma separate strings ? can you please give a small example ?

Comment: now getting this error   Syntax error in module 'controller': positional argument follows keyword argument (dynamo_dal.py, line 65)  when I passed  `ProjectionExpression = "USER_ID","NODE_TYPE" `

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52994822/using-a-projectionexpression-with-reserved-words-with-boto3-in-dynamodb